# Верна ли пунктуация в предложении и есть ли в нём присоединительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, бсп, присоединительный

Скажите, пожалуйста, возможна ли такая пунктуация и можно ли считать часть со "скорее всего..." присоединительным оборотом?

*Я обернулся, но его уже не было — скорее всего, побежал ябедничать.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (06.08.2023)**

"Грамота.ру" ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310714)):

> Вводным сочетанием *скорее всего* начинается третья часть сложного
> предложения, соединенная со второй частью бессоюзной связью. Эта часть
> имеет значение причины, обоснования (отвечая на вопрос «Почему его уже
> не было?»), и вместо тире лучше поставить двоеточие.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Я обернулся, но его уже не было — скорее всего, побежал ябедничать.***

Да, пунктуация верна. Тире здесь самый подходящий знак. Только часть после тире не оборот, а целое предложение, которое можно считать присоединительным.
Рассказчик высказывает своё предположение, попутную мысль.

[**Присоединительные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120) (справочник Розенталя):

> **1.** Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) **запятыми** (реже используются **тире, точка, многоточие**).
> <...>
> **4.** Знаками препинания выделяются не только присоединительные члены предложения, но и присоединительные предложения.

[**Присоединительные конструкции**](https://topuch.com/udk-811-161-1-bbk-81-2rus-92-3-v-15/index52.html) (Валгина Н. С., Розенталь Д. Э., Фомина М. И. Современный русский язык):

> Функция дополнительно возникшего высказывания определяет основные значения присоединительных конструкций: они имеют характер добавочных сообщений, уточняющих, поясняющих и развивающих основное высказывание. Все эти качества позволяют считать присоединительные конструкции особым синтаксическим явлением. Цель использования присоединения — придать речи особые смысловые и экспрессивно-стилистические оттенки, сообщить отдельным членам высказывания большую смысловую и эмоциональную нагрузку.

Comment: Голосую за ваш ответ, но определенные сомнения у меня есть. Во-первых, хотелось точнее определить семантику и грамматику второй части. Мне кажется, что здесь все-таки присоединительное предложение со значением авторского предположения, а не БСП. У Розенталя есть  похожий пример: «Внезапно мальчик исчез — умер, или, возможно, его похитили». Во-вторых,  меня постоянно огорчает цитата о «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире — вы считаете, что они действительно борются?

Comment: Но ведь есть еще разделительное тире (с повышением голоса), которое нельзя заменить двоеточием — это возможно только для присоединительного тире (там в обоих случаях голос понижается перед паузой), но зато паузы разные. Ну и семантические оттенки, а также область применения в грамматике  у каждого варианта тоже есть.  А интонационное предупреждение (по Розенталю) характерно только для двоеточия.  Поэтому выбрать между  ними наилучший вариант можно.

Comment: @Sharon Наилучший вариант – тире (я просто его люблю :)), и оно, как мне кажется, действительно вытесняет двоеточие, по крайней мере конкурирует во многих случаях). А что касается структуры: разве предложение с двумя основами, вторая из которых присоединение (на чём я акцентирую внимание как в начале, так и в конце ответа) не является по сути БСП?

Comment: Любите, да? Ну тогда нет вопросов)) Если тире и вытесняет двоеточие,  то это связано  с динамичность нашей жизни, с более упрощенной структурой современных предложений. И о разнице между БСП и присоединительными конструкциями. По Розенталю, присоединительные члены  содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, а вот для БСП это нехарактерно. Там тоже есть присоединительно-распространительное значение, но это выглядит примерно так: Времени мало – вот что плохо. Из леса доносились глухие удары – это лесорубы валили деревья. Здесь вторая часть входит в основное содержание предложения.

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо! Убрал лишнюю информацию.

Comment: Да, теперь всё ШИКИБЛЕСК  (это из детского сленга в книге Н. Абгарян «Манюня», очень ее люблю). Пора принимать ваш ответ! Как говорится, «где же наш пахарь, чего еще ждет?»

Answer (score 0):

Так:

**Я обернулся, но его уже не было, — скорее всего, побежал ябедничать**.

Или:

**Я обернулся, но его уже не было. Скорее всего, побежал ябедничать**.

Или:

**Я обернулся, но его уже не было, скорее всего побежал ябедничать**.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).